# View included by $this->include does note receive passed params

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

Is possible pass parameter to view when i use $this->include method in another view?

In example:

```
<?php
foreach ($destaques as $camping) {
    $this->include('partial', ['camping' => $camping])
}
?>
```

But partial.php dont receive $camping value.

Answer (score 1):

When using `$this->include` you're making an `echo` of a view into an other one. So by default, the view you're loading will have acces to any data you gave to the parent view but not variables you declared into it.
A few options in your case :

**Using the view method :**

```
foreach ($destaques as $camping) {
        echo view('partial', ['camping' => $camping]);
    }
```

**Moving your foreach loop in the partial view** so you'll use `$destaques` into it.

```
   <?php
       // dont forget to echo
       echo $this->include('partial')
   ?>

   // or this way with short tags enabled
   <?= $this->include('partial') ?>
```

And just embed your partial view in your previous foreach loop

```
foreach ($destaques as $camping) {
    // whatever your partial view is
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello I try using the parameter option. I test code and it s working. But note the include view layout method work like php default include function and it does not display until you echo it.
Here is my code which I use to test yours and it worked for me. Check it

```php
$inc = '';
foreach ($destaques as $camping) {
    $inc .= $this->include('partial', ['camping' => $camping])
}
echo $inc;
```

And this displayed and worked for me check it. if this is not what you were expecting, just call my attention